# Replacing all umlauts simultaneously in R (using regex)

Tags: r, regex

I have text in German and I want to replace all umlauts (ä, Ä, ü, Ü, ö, Ö) with ae, oe, ue, etc.

I can do it separately (by saving each substitution into a new file):

```
gsub(pattern = '[ä]', replacement = "ae",text)
gsub(pattern = '[ü]', replacement = "ue",text)
gsub(pattern = '[ö]', replacement = "oe",text)
```

But can I do it in one command (including substituting capital letters with Ae, Oe and Ue, etc.)?

Can I do it by regex?

Comment: You probably can't do the actual work in one line, but you can define a function that does just this...

Comment: @Rhymoid for example?

Comment: You could use `stringr::str_replace_all` to replace them all at once if you pass it a named vector where names are patterns and elements are replacements, e.g. `stringr::str_replace_all('üïëäö', c('ü' = 'ue', 'ï' = 'ie', 'ë' = 'ee', 'ä' = 'ae','ö' = 'oe'))` (add capitals if you like). You might dig into stringi, though; you can just remove accents with `stringi::stri_trans_general('üïëäö', 'latin-ascii')`, though it won't insert "e"s.

Comment: Which character set are you using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try

```
# install.packages("stringi) # uncomment & run if needed
str <- c("äöü", "ÄÖÜ")
stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(
  str, 
  c("ä", "ö", "ü", "Ä", "Ö", "Ü"), 
  c("ae", "oe", "ue", "Ae", "Oe", "Ue"), 
  vectorize_all = FALSE
)
# [1] "aeoeue" "AeOeUe"
```

Answer (score 9):

Some solutions here might or might not work depending on the locale of the OS running R and the encoding of the input string. I had this problem many times on different OS and different language settings. Currently I am developing R using German Windows 10 but sometimes run the code on an English Ubuntu VM.

A very fast and reliable solution under both Windows and Ubuntu, both de_DE and en_US is this solution:
https://github.com/gagolews/stringi/issues/269#issuecomment-488623874

```
> stringi::stri_trans_general("ä ö ü ß", "de-ASCII; Latin-ASCII")
[1] "ae oe ue ss"
```

The `;` inside of the ICU transform id makes this a 'compound id'. See `?stri_trans_general` for more info.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways. Two of them have been suggested above depeding on either the `stringi` or `stringr` package.

Another solution uses the `gsubfn`package.

```
text <- "ae = ä und oe = ö, UE = Ü. I also want Ä to be AE and not Ae"

# Solution depends on extra package "gsubfn"
require(gsubfn)
gsubfn(".", list("ä"="ae", "ö"="oe", "ü"="ue", "Ä" = "AE", "Ö" = "OE", "Ü" = "UE"), text)
```

Of course, we can also write our own function because you probably don't want to load a package just because you need a single function (I personally try to avoid that).

```
# Solution 1
replace_umlauts <- function(x) {
  umlauts <- "äöü"
  UMLAUTS <- "ÄÖÜ"
  x <- gsub(pattern = paste0("([", UMLAUTS, "])"), replacement = "\\1E", x)
  x <- gsub(pattern = paste0("([", umlauts, "])"), replacement = "\\1e", x)
  x <- chartr(old = paste0(UMLAUTS, umlauts), new = "AOUaou", x)
  return(x)
}
replace_umlauts(text)
```

The interesting part is the benchmark.

```
require(microbenchmark)
require(stringi)
require(stringr)
require(gsubfn)
microbenchmark(
  myown = replace_umlauts(text),
  stringi = stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed(text, c("ä", "ö", "ü", "Ä", "Ö", "Ü"), c("ae", "oe", "ue", "AE", "OE", "UE"), vectorize_all = FALSE),
  stringr = stringr::str_replace_all(text, c("ü" = "ue", "ä" = "ae", "ö" = "oe", "Ä" = "AE", "Ö" = "OE", "Ü" = "UE")), 
  gsubfn = gsubfn(".", list("ä"="ae", "ö"="oe", "ü"="ue", "Ä" = "AE", "Ö" = "OE", "Ü" = "UE"), text),
  times = 500L
)
```

The results are:

```
Unit: microseconds
    expr   min      lq      mean  median     uq    max neval
   myown  18.1   23.50   28.8510   30.45   32.6   63.3   500
 stringi  10.5   14.10   17.3808   17.80   19.8   46.3   500
 stringr 332.3  353.40  375.5458  371.85  387.5  586.1   500
  gsubfn 996.5 1042.55 1104.7458 1057.45 1075.2 7547.5   500
```

The fastest solution is `stringi::stri_replace_all_fixed`. IOt's almost twice as fast as the second best solution and 10 times faster than `stringr`. The only acceptable alternative  in matters of speed is the homemade `replace_umlauts` function.