# Replacement of big and small letters in R(gsub)

Tags: r, regex

I want to replace all Umlauts(German) in my text. Here is the part of my text:

```
temp.RData enthalten die täglichen Niederschlagsmengen\nund die stündlichen Durchschnittstemperaturen von 1.7.2016 (1 Uhr) bis\n26.9.2016
```

So I want to replace all letters like ä,ü and ö by their english analogues(ae,ue,oe)

Here is my code:

```
text <- gsub(pattern = '[Ää]',replacement = "ae",text)
text <- gsub(pattern = '[Üü]',replacement = "ue",text)
text <- gsub(pattern = '[Öö]',replacement = "oe",text)
```

Everything works fine, except that bit umlauts(Ä,Ü,Ö) were replaced by analogues, which begins from small letter . But i want to replace Ä by Ae(not ae). How can I do that using only `regex` in R?

Comment: Is it not the same question, Danil? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40323219/replacing-all-umlauts-simultaneously-in-r-using-regex/40323338#40323338

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way, especially if you want to be selective, is to separate it out:

```
text <- gsub(pattern = '[ä]',replacement = "ae",text)
text <- gsub(pattern = '[ü]',replacement = "ue",text)
text <- gsub(pattern = '[ö]',replacement = "oe",text)
text <- gsub(pattern = '[Ä]',replacement = "Ae",text)
text <- gsub(pattern = '[Ü]',replacement = "Ue",text)
text <- gsub(pattern = '[Ö]',replacement = "Oe",text)
```

If you want a more efficient way, you can use `stringr`

```
library(stringr) 
str_replace_all(text, c('ä' = 'ae', 'ë' = 'ee', 'ï' = 'ie', 'ö' = 'oe',
                        'ü' = 'ue', 'Ä' = 'Ae', 'Ë' = 'Ee', 'Ï' = 'Ie',
                        'Ö' = 'Oe', 'Ü' = 'Ue'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a faster and more parsimonious method using the Unicode-smart **stringi** package:

```
txt <- "A: Äbel bäbel, O: Öber öber, U: Über über gemütlich"
stringi:: stri_replace_all_fixed(txt, 
                                 c("ä", "ü", "ö", "Ä", "Ü", "Ö"), 
                                 c("ae", "ue", "oe", "Ae", "Ue", "Oe"), 
                                 vectorize_all = FALSE)
## [1] "A: Aebel baebel, O: Oeber oeber, U: Ueber ueber gemuetlich"
```

The `vectorize_all = FALSE` means that your substitutions are element-by-element, and making this a fixed pattern replacement makes it the fastest possible.